# smooth piecewise and integrable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

any riemann integrable function is a smooth piecewise function?

Is true for fundamental theorem calculus?

Comment: Riemann integrable or Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: in riemann sense

Comment: What does your second sentence mean?

Comment: Do you know the Riemann function on $[0,1]$, which means sending $p/q$ to $1/q$ with coprime $p,q$, and zeros elsewhere, this is Riemann integrable, but is this piecewise smooth?

Comment: the function is for hypothesis riemann integrable

Comment: Does piecewise mean finitely many pieces?

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Thomae's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function). This function is continuous on all irrational numbers, hence is Riemann integrable by Lebesgue's criterion of Riemann integrability, but it is not piecewise smooth.

Answer (score 0):

No, and here are a few examples:

- The indicator function of the Cantor set
- Any nowhere differentiable continuous function. As they are locally bounded and continuous, they are integrable on any compact interval
- As @user284331 and @ Henry W. pointed out, you can look up Thomae's function (also known as Stars over Babylon)